# CCAvenue integration not working Error 10002

Tags: java, jsp, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I am working on integrating CCAvenue with our website. Our company account has an approved CCAvenue account. Before publishing I would like to test integration on local test setup.

As CCAvenue processes transactions initiated from registered web store URL, I have added entries in hosts file for mapping domain name as

```
127.0.01 www.ourwebsite.com
```

On CCAvenue we have registered with same web store url - http://www.ourwebsite.com

I have double checked that my `access_code` and `Working key` entries are correct. My test transaction gets initiated from URL `www.ourwebsite.com/test` and for testing purpose I am using `https://test.ccavenue.com`

But I am getting error as

```
Error Code: 10002     Merchant Authentication failed.

Don't worry... It happens to the best of us.
```

My doubt is does the web store URL has to be exact same as the URL which initiates the transaction or only domain name should work?

Comment: A comment would have been appreciated for why downvoted the question! and if you know the solution then it would be better if you post it..

Comment: Same thing happened with me too. I mailed the costumer care and they told me to use  this URL -   
https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems there is some problem with ccavenue testing server because when I tested my integration with live(real) server everything worked fine.

Comment: The same happened with me. It seems I was using an older version **(1.1)** of **CCAvenue**. I've not tested the newer version **(3.1)**, but your solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If, only the test account is not working but the secure (real) account is working then drop a mail to service@ccavenue.com to activate your testing account. You have to send the merchant ID along with website URL in the mail.